# How to call the camera on mobile device by the "fineuploader" library?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, image-uploading, fine-uploader

## [Fine Uploader Javascript Upload Library](http://fineuploader.com/)

[document for  "Upload from Mobile Device Cameras"](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/upload-from-mobile-camera.html)

The following code Tested Browsers and Systems:

1. Safari - iOS 10.2
2. Chrome - Android 6.0

code：

```
$(function() {
    var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        callbacks: {
            onAllComplete: function(suc, fail) {
                addBtnAttr();
            }
        }
    });

    function addBtnAttr() {
        $("input[type=file]").attr({
            accept: "image/*",
            capture: "camera"
        });
    }
    addBtnAttr();
});
```

that can work!

But this does not use API provided by the fine-uploader library.

#### Is there a better way or the right way to call camera on mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

According to [**Capture Attribute**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/#dfn-media-capture-mechanism),

And **Fine-Uploader** only provided [`accept`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#validation.acceptFiles) interface, there is no `capture` interface,

so only,

```
$(function() {
  new qq.FineUploader({
      element: ...,
      request: {
          endpoint: '...'
      },
      callbacks: {
          onAllComplete: function(suc, fail) {
              addCaptureAttr();
          }
      },
      validation: {
          acceptFiles: 'image/*;'
      }
  });

  function addCaptureAttr() {
      //if only one input with file type
      $("input[type=file]").attr({
          capture: "camera" //(or any "truthy values")
      });
  }
  addCaptureAttr();
});
```

Comment: I'm not convinced this is necessary. What happens when you use my solution? On iOS, it works as expected, and I would expect it to work on Android as well.